# Issue with Google Drive files marked as hidden

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have an iOS app that uses the google-api-objectivec-client library to access Google Drive accounts. In general everything works fine. But I've run into one strange issue.

A user used Windows Explorer on their computer to create a folder in their Google Drive account and also used Windows Explorer to add files to this folder. If I create a query with:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
```

the files in the folder created in Windows Explorer come back with the 'hidden' label set to true. Files added through the web interface at drive.google.com don't have this problem. And these "hidden" files appear just fine in the web interface.

I also found one of my own files, uploaded to my Google Drive account using the web interface, appears with the 'hidden' label set to true. I can't find anything in the web interface that would affect this setting.

So two questions.

1. Why are these files flagged as hidden even though they show up in the web interface?
2. What's the proper way to handle these files? I don't want to just ignore this flag. I would think hidden files should be hidden. But these files shouldn't be hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that "hidden" merely means hidden from 'files in root' display. If the file is in a folder, then 'hidden' has no significance.

**EDIT Sept 2014
I notice that the "hidden" property has been deprecated by Google.**
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes sense and it matches both cases but I'd love a definitive answer from the Google Drive folks. The Google Drive docs simply state that hidden means "Whether the file is hidden or not." That's pretty vague.